# Renumbering rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I'm kinda new into the SQL Server and I'm having the following question: is there any possibility to renumber the rows in a column?

For ex:

```
id  date         name
1   2016-01-02   John
2   2016-01-02   Jack
3   2016-01-02   John
4   2016-01-02   John
5   2016-01-03   Jack
6   2016-01-03   Jack
7   2016-01-04   John
8   2016-01-03   Jack
9   2016-01-02   John
10  2016-01-04   Jack
```

I would like that all "Johns" to start with id 1 and go on (2, 3, 4 etc) and all "Jacks" have the following number when "John" is done (5, 6, 7 etc). Thanks!

Comment: If `id` is the primary key you should not change it's values.

Comment: A pivot question i think :).. can you tag your DBMS ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Tim is right: if `id` is the primary key, there is no need to do this (and it will be quite hard if that table is referenced by others)

Comment: Why? The id is just an id and has no other meaning.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - column id is not primary key.. i'm importing some data from another app with different dates, and I want all Johns, no matter what date, to start from 1 and end with 20, and all Jacks, no matter what date, to start from 20 and end with whatever number.

Comment: @cdrrr and what if you have 21 Johns?

Comment: @B0Andrew - starting from 1 and end with 21

Comment: and what if you have 21 Johns then later you have 22 Johns? Do you want to go and shuffle up all Jacks? I suggest you explain the real problem because this one doesn't make much sense so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps..

```
declare @t table (id  int ,[date] date,name varchar(20))
insert into @t
        ( id, date, name )
values  (1,'2016-01-02','John')
,(2,'2016-01-02','Jack')
,(3,'2016-01-02','John')
,(4,'2016-01-02','John')
,(5,'2016-01-03','Jack')
,(6,'2016-01-03','Jack')
,(7,'2016-01-04','John')
,(8,'2016-01-03','Jack')
,(9,'2016-01-02','John')
,(10,'2016-01-04','Jack')

select 
    row_number() over(order by name,[date]) as ID,
    date ,
    name 
from 
    @t
order by name
```

Answer (score 1):

The `id` should just be an internal identifier you use for joins etc - I wouldn't change it. But you could query such a numbering using a window function:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE name WHEN 'John' THE 1 ELSE 2 END) AS rn,
       date,
       name
FROM   mytable
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of renumbering the id column, you can use `ROW_NUMBER` window function to renumber the rows as per your requirement. for e.g.:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date) as rowid,date,name
FROM tablename
```